# add image over an element

Tags: css

Is it possible to add a transparent image (like stripe) over an element without javascript or adding an other element in html, a css foreground technique.
Something like an experiment `border-image` inside with a `box-sizing:border-box;` or something like `:after` ?

```
<div class="striped">lorem ipsum dolores</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it, for example using `:after` - http://jsfiddle.net/U3rfH/

Just change the background color to your background image:

```
div {
   margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(200, 0, 200, .2);
}
```